# React navigation navigation.navigate doesn't go to next screen while using camera

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-native-camera

I am using react-navigation 3.6.1 an react-native-camera 2.2.2. When I take a picture the button to go to the next screen takes doesn't do nothing at first press. Has to be pressed multiple times

This is for react native 0.59.4 in ios development. The same buttons for navigating on any other screen on the app works perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a workaround : add the prop

```
   onPressIn=navigation.navigate()
```